# SQL Query returns incorrect count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the count of all the **feature** and the feature name against an application by using MySQL query. Here is the query:
`select t2.feature,count(t2.feature) as count from judge_task t1, approve t2 where t1.application_name='Retail Bank Portal'  AND t2.gap_status=1 group by feature;`
Here is the description of my tables:
Table **judge_task**

```
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| application_id   | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| application_name | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| feature_id       | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| feature_name     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| task_type        | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Table **approve**

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| feature          | varchar(500) | NO   |     | 0       |                |


| gap_status       | int          | NO   |     | 3       |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There is no relationship like **foreign key** between both the tables. The database was designed by someone else and it can not be updated now as the application is almost completed. Updating the database will disturb the whole application design.
Here is the result of the query:

```
+---------+-----+
| feature | app |
+---------+-----+
| S3      | 175 |
| Login   | 875 |
+---------+-----+
```

The original count are as follows:
**S3 = 1,
Login = 5**

I am not getting the exact query to get my results. Would you please suggest me a correction to my query? How should I update it to get my results? Thanks a lot
**Update 1**

sample data for judge_task is here

```
| 100173 |              4 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         1 |
| 100203 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         2 |
| 100204 |              4 | Retail Bank Portal |         19 | Bill Pay                |         2 |
| 100205 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         2 |
| 100206 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         2 |
| 100207 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         2 |
| 100208 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         16 | Login                   |         2 |
| 100209 |             -1 | Retail Bank Portal |         22 | S3                      |         2 |
```

Sample data for **approve**

```
|  59 | Login                   |          1 |
|  60 | Login                   |          1 |
| 115 | Login                   |          1 |
| 116 | Login                   |          1 |
| 117 | Login                   |          3 |
| 118 | Login                   |          3 |
| 119 | Login                   |          3 |
| 120 | Login                   |          3 |
| 121 | Login                   |          3 |
| 122 | Login                   |          3 |
| 123 | Login                   |          3 |
| 124 | Login                   |          3 |
| 125 | Login                   |          3 |
| 126 | Login                   |          3 |
| 127 | Login                   |          3 |
| 128 | Login                   |          1 |
| 129 | S3                      |          1 |
+-----+-------------------------+------------+
```

I have updated the table definitions according to sample data removing the irrelevant columns. Thanks

**Update**
One thing I forget to mention that the data has to be selected from approve table and just the application name is to be selected from judge_task.

Comment: Certainly there is some relationship between these two tables.  If not, then you would be stuck with doing a cross join which isn't what you want here.

Comment: @MatBailie sorry for that. Could you please suggest which join should be used here? That would be really helpful

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what should I be using here then? Thanks

Comment: Some sample data would be very helpful, if you have it.

Comment: You clearly get 175 rows from the `judge_task` table, and just 6 rows from the `approve` table.  I'd start by visually inspecting those rows, deciding on the results you'd want, and then updating this question using some example data.

Comment: I will just post some sample data here

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the table definitions and the sample data so that you may have not too many columns in the table while testing. Thanks

Comment: @MatBailie  I have updated the table definitions and the sample data so that you may have not too many columns in the table while testing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd make the query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.feature, t.feature_count
FROM judge_task
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      app.feature, COUNT(*) AS feature_count
    FROM approve app
    WHERE app.gap_status = 1
    GROUP BY app.feature
  ) AS t ON t.feature = judge_task.feature_name
WHERE judge_task.application_name = 'Retail Bank Portal'
;
```

You can see the result in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c70c5bc/7/0)

With the inner select you can avoid duplication of result due to the Cartesian product with the `approve` table

Comment: that is totally a new way to query for me as I have been away from database for more than a year.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a(n implicit) CROSS JOIN with your query, which means, all rows from table A are combined with table B in the background.

First find the way you can explicitly join your tables (feature_id = feature.id maybe?)

Use explicit join (INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, etc) instead of implicit one (listing the tables with comas in the FROM clause).

Comment: is not there any way I could get from the current table schema?

Answer (score 0):

First: you do not need a foreign key to join two tables in a query. All you need is a field in both tables with the "same data", that allows to acreate this relation, for example, a "TaskID" or anything like this (the name of the field is not nesessary the same).
The only fields in your tables that allow to create this connection in your tables are: *judge_task.feature_name* and *approve.feature*. I guess we can try this query:

```
select t2.feature, count(t2.id) from judge_task as t1 
join approve as t2 on t2.feature = t1.feature_name
where t1.application_name='Retail Bank Portal'  AND t2.gap_status=1 
group by feature;
```

If your tables have many rows I recommend that you create indexes on *judge_task.feature_name* and *approve.feature* (as well as on judge_task.application_name) to improve performance.

Comment: it returns the following :
 | Login   |          285 |
| S3      |            3 |

that doesn't look like the correct query.